# How to use a custom attribute rather than value in this JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of value, I'd like to use 'test' for instance. I've tried finding the correct way of doing this but none of my methods are working. value is already being used for something else. If you have any workaround that'd be great.

This code is working properly with "value" being the attr of the option element.

```js
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.fn.chainedTo = function (parentSelector = "",debugRules = false) {
        var $child = $(this);
        var thisChildId = "#" + $child[0].id;

        function setIdChild($id, childId) {
            if (typeof $id.data('updateChild') === 'undefined') {
                $id.attr('data-update-child', childId);
            } else {
                $id.attr('data-update-child', $id.attr('data-update-child') + ',' + childId);
            }
        };
        function setIdParent($id, parentId) {
            if (typeof $id.data('selectParent') === 'undefined') {
                $id.data('selectParent', new Array(parentId.split(",")));
            } else {
                $id.data('selectParent', $id.data('selectParent').concat(parentId.split(",")));
            }
        };
        function saveIdOldState($id) {
            if (typeof $id.data('old-state') === 'undefined') {
                $id.data('old-state', $id.html());
            }
        };

        function matchRule(str, rules, debugRules = false) {
            if (debugRules) console.log('      Parent values to match: ' + str);
            if (debugRules) console.log("      Rules to match with: " + rules);
            var ruleArr = rules;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < ruleArr.length; i++) {
                let thisRuleText = ruleArr[i].split("*").join(".*").split("+").join("\\+");
                let thisRule = new RegExp(thisRuleText);
                if (debugRules) console.log("      - Checking with RegExp: " + thisRule);

                if (thisRule.test(str)) {
                    if (debugRules) console.log("      # MATCHED on rule: " + thisRule);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (debugRules) console.log("      # NO MATCH found");
            return false;
        };
        function updateSelections($id) {
            //restore the original state for this select
            $id.html($id.data('old-state'));
            if ($id.attr('data-debug-rules') == "true") {
                var debugRules = true;
            }
            //get the current value of the parents we want to match, join with '+'
            if (typeof $id.data('selectParent') === 'undefined')
                return true;
            var parentVal = $($id.data('selectParent').join(",")).map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join("+");
            var newInnerHTML = [];
            //loop through each of the select options and remove where the parent value is not found
            if (debugRules) console.log("==> Evaluating select id: #" +$id.attr('id'));
            $id.children().each(function (k, value) {
                if (debugRules) console.log  (" -> Evaluating select option with text: " + value.innerText.trim());
                if (matchRule(parentVal, value.getAttribute('data-available-with').split(","), debugRules)) {
                    newInnerHTML += (value.outerHTML);
                }
            });
            $id.html(newInnerHTML);


        };


        function ClickTab(e) {
            if (typeof $(e.target).attr('data-update-child') === 'undefined')
                return true;

            //get and split the children. For each of those, update the valid selections.
            for (let i = 0; i < $(e.target).attr('data-update-child').split(",").length; i++) {
                updateSelections($($(e.target).attr('data-update-child').split(",")[i]));
            }
            return false;
        };

        //Save the original state of the select in a datafield
        saveIdOldState($child);
//        console.log($(parentSelector));

        //enabling rules debug if requested
        if (debugRules) $child.attr('data-debug-rules', 'true');

        //configure a change trigger on the parent selector
        $(parentSelector).filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('updateChild') === undefined;
        }).change(ClickTab);

        //add a data record to the parent that links it to the child
        $(parentSelector).each(function (k, v) {
            setIdChild($(v), thisChildId);
//            console.log("parentSelector each value: ", $(v));
        });

        //add a data record to the child that links it to the parent.
        setIdParent($child, parentSelector);

        //update the selections right now.
        updateSelections($child);


        // return jQuery object
        return this;
    };


})(jQuery, window, document);




    $("#desktoptype").chainedTo("#datacenter");
    // $("#os").chainedTo("#datacenter,#desktoptype");
    $("#os").chainedTo("#desktoptype");
    $("#bu").chainedTo("#datacenter,#desktoptype,#os");
    $("#as").chainedTo("#bu");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="chained-set">
        <select id="datacenter" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">ONE+</option>
        </select>

        <select id="desktoptype" class="form-control">
            <option value="1" data-available-with="1">ONE RUN</option>
            <option value="2" data-available-with="2">ONE+ RUN</option>
        </select>
        <select id="os" class="form-control">
            <option value="1" data-available-with="1,2">1 Color</option>
            <option value="3" data-available-with="1,2">2 Colors</option>
        </select>
        <select id="bu" class="form-control">
   <option value="" data-available-with="1,2">No</option>
            <option value="4" data-available-with="1,2">Yes</option>
        </select>
  <select id="as" class="form-control">
   <option value="4" data-available-with="4">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

I would like it to work if I updated the HTML to have "test" be the attr of the option elements.

```html
 <fieldset id="chained-set">
        <select id="datacenter" class="form-control">
            <option test="1">ONE</option>
            <option test="2">ONE+</option>
        </select>
        <select id="desktoptype" class="form-control">
            <option test="1" data-available-with="1">ONE RUN</option>
            <option test="2" data-available-with="2">ONE+ RUN</option>
        </select>
        <select id="os" class="form-control">
            <option test="1" data-available-with="1,2">1 Color</option>
            <option test="3" data-available-with="1,2">2 Colors</option>
        </select>
        <select id="bu" class="form-control">
   <option test="" data-available-with="1,2">No</option>
            <option test="4" data-available-with="1,2">Yes</option>
        </select>
  <select id="as" class="form-control">
   <option test="4" data-available-with="4">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Given that `test` is a non-standard attribute, you should make it `data-test` if you are going to do that.  And then to get it is simply using `data('test')`

Comment: I understand; however, I'm unsure what I'd update in the JS for even that.

Comment: I mean, if value was what you were using before, and now value is changed to data-test, you just replace the places that you were using value with the data call.  What's confusing you?

Comment: This is not my JS code. It's from a plugin. It works great when I use value="#" but I want to use another attr like test="#" or data-test="#" whatever works.  I'm unsure where to make this edit in the JS to make this change, do you?

Comment: You have way to much code and examples.  You should reduce the examples code/html to exactly what you need, not the entire scope of what you're trying to create.  For example, saying you have the wrong size wrench to take off a tire, we don't care what kind of car it is, nor the gas it uses.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not a standard HTML attribute, hence it will not work for your use case. Rather, HTML5 introduced what we call custom data attributes. These allow us to store arbitrary strings as attributes in our HTML. Custom data attributes start with `data-` to avoid confusion and to distinguish the attribute as unique to your page.

This code looks like it uses jQuery. jQuery has an interface for interacting with element data that may be good for your use case. I would recommend reading the API documentation at [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Comment: If I were to change it to data-test, what exactly would you change in the JS to make this work?

Comment: I see you are using jQuery in this case. jQuery offers a special set of functions for interacting with custom data attributes. These involve using `.data()` functions instead of `.attr()`. Take a look at the link I posted above for more information on this special feature of jQuery.

Comment: Please take a look at the JS written above, what would you update in order to get it to look at .data('test') instead of value?

Comment: Where do you feel the code needs to be changed? We're only here to point you in the right direction. You have a large example and we can't see the big picture. The onus to write the revised code is ultimately on you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to retrieve data from a html element that is custom, use the [HTML5 data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) option with [jQuery's `.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-blah]').each(function(i,e){
    var $this = $(e);
    var data = $this.data('blah');
    $this.text(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-blah="asdf" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>
<div data-blah="qwert" style="border: 1px solid green;"></div>
```